# convert list of keys to nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to create, for example, a dictionary that looks like this: `d[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]]` from a list like this : `keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]` ...

I've tried the following:

```
  keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
  d = {}
  d_ref= d
  for key_num, key in enumerate(keys):
    if key_num < len(keys)-1:
      d[key] = {}
      d_ref = d[key]
    else:
      d_ref[key] = []
  print(d)
```

but it results in this:

`{'key1': {}, 'key2': {'key3': []}}`

I'm aiming for this output:

`{'key1' : { 'key2' : { "key3" : [] } } }`

### Update

Thanks to wim for the answer that led me to my desired result:

```
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
d = []
for key in reversed(keys):
   d = {key: d}

print(d)
```

Comment: No need to use `enumerate` and `if`. See my answer for a one-liner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a simple for-loop should do the trick

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for k in reversed(keys):
...     d = {k: d}
...     
>>> d
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': {}}}}
```

(***edit***:  *OP changed the question after posting*)  Should you want a list as initial value, just change the first assignment:

```
>>> d = []
>>> for k in reversed(keys):
...     d = {k: d}
...     
>>> d
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': []}}}
```

Comment: nice! I was trying to do a sort of linked list type of iteration maintaining the pointer to the most recent dictionary but apparantly i was unable to do that lol

Comment: I'll accept this, i've modified it to create my desired result. Thanks!! (*see my answer edit)

Comment: Or you can just do instead of `idx` etc `d = [];for k in reversed(keys): d = {k: d}`

Answer (score 3):

After an edit made by the OP, the solution is now a one-liner:

```
result = reduce(lambda obj, key: {key: obj}, reversed(keys), [])
# {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': []}}}
```

Or with some functional programming:

```
from functools import reduce
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
result = reduce((lambda obj, key: {key: obj}), reversed(keys), dict())
print(result)
# {'key1': {'key2': {'key3': {}}}}
```

Comment: I like your ans! `result = reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(keys), [])`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ajax1234 that this problem has a recursive flavor to it but I think it can be done much simpler code than his solution:

```
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

def nest(keys, value):
    key, *rest = keys

    if rest:
        value = nest(rest, value)

    return {key: value}

print(nest(keys, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
def get_dictionary(s, d):
   if not s[1:]:
      return {s[0]:d}
   else:
      if not d:
          return get_dictionary(s[1:], {s[0]:[]})
      else:
          return get_dictionary(s[1:], {s[0]:d})


print(get_dictionary(["key1", "key2", "key3"][::-1], {}))
```

Output:

```
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': []}}}
```